# Error al conectarme a la base de datos: "error": "Login failed for user 'xxx'."

Tags: nodejs, sequelize.js

Tengo problemas para conectarme a una base de datos es `MSSQL`, utilizo `sequelize` y `tedious`. Tedious esta utilizando el usuario de mi computador para realizar la conexión mas no el que recibe por parametro desde mi archivo `.env`

```
version **sequelize: 6.16.2**
version **tedious : ^11.0.5**
```

El error que arroja es:

```
"error": "Login failed for user 'nombredemipc'."
```

Comment: Mi pregunta es ¿`Mysql` tiene algún usuario que se llame literal `nombredemipc`?

Answer (score 0):

Usa este:

```
$conn = mssql_connect ("127.0.0.1 O tu IP externa", "Usuario", "Pass") or die("Conection ERROR Mssql o libreria no existe");
```

PD asegurate de abrir la IP en el firewall solo para donde tengas alojada la web el puerto por defecto es el 1433.